# Persistent Multiple Choice List - ArrayList reset

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment

The Android documentation provides the following code for a multiple choice `DialogFragment` and describes it as a "persistent multiple-choice list"

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)
            // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
            // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                mSelectedItems.add(which);
                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    })
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
               ...
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               ...
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

The selected items are saved in the ArrayList and the selected items ARE persistent in terms of staying selected on orientation change, BUT the ArrayList is reset and if I send it back to my activity via an interface, I send a new empty ArrayList.

Do I have to override `onSaveInstanceState` or am I missing something here?

Comment: I have the same Question, We can understand list with radioBtns as persistant  but list with checkboxes is not persistent..then how we can keep set the selected items if dialog opens again?